# Universal macro for getting number elements in array or return just 1 when is used on variable?

Tags: c, macros, sizeof, c99

In C language macro for getting number of array elements is well known and looks like this:

```
uint32_t buffer[10];

#define ARRAY_SIZE(x)     sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])

size_t size = ARRAY_SIZE(buffer);
```

The question is, is there any universal macro for getting array elements or returning just one when it's used on variable ? I mean following usage of macro :

```
uint32_t buffer[10];
uint32_t variable;

#define GET_ELEMENTS(x)     ???

size_t elements_of_array = GET_ELEMENTS(buffer); // returns 10
size_t elements_of_variable = GET_ELEMENTS(variable); // returns 1
```

Does anybody know the solution ?

I've edited my question because it was wrongly formulated, BTW I know that I can use :

```
sizeof(variable)/sizeof(uint32_t)
```

Question is how to combine it in one macro or maybe inline function is better solution ?

Comment: Yes, it's called `sizeof`.

Comment: Notice that, when passed as formal arguments, arrays are decayed into pointers. And there is no portable magic way to get the size of a memory zone pointed by some given pointer.

Comment: If you're going to use the `ARRAY_SIZE` macro, it should really be `#define`d as something like `(sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sizeof`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned int buffer[10];
  // size of one unsigned int
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(unsigned int));

  // this will print the number of elements of buffer * size of an unsigned int
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(buffer));

  // you have a mistake
  // the following printf() gives you the number of elements
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]));
  return 0;
}
```

Output (on my machine):

```
4
40
10
```

Regarding the edit you made:

You [can't perform type checking in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280055/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-of-a-certain-type-compare-two-types-in-c), thus you can not check if what you pass is an array or a variable.

Comment: You're right I got a mistake there, I've edited my question it should be now more meaningful question.

Comment: @Lazureus: It's now a different question, which kind of invalidates all comments and answers up to now.

Comment: Thank you for answer, unfortunately I've already edited my question here, I don't want to make additional mess, if you got proper answer for edited question please post it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: As you wish. What exactly do you want now? A macro that performs the division?@Lazureus I mean I think it's OK the way it is. :)

Comment: Macro which can return number of elements from array or return 1 when variable is passed to it.

Comment: And how to determine if what we pass in a macro is an array or a variable? This is really a different question. However, I feel that you understood what I answered so far, so I will vote up your question for balance. @Lazureus

Comment: @Lazureus I am done with the research and I think you can't do what you asked me for in the comment.

Comment: @Lazureus let me say that I didn't take back my upvote. However, I do not know why you are not accepting the answer. Don't you agree with it?

Comment: @G.Samaras Sorry for answering so late but I needed to investigate this link which you gave me. I've tried create this macro basing on some condition statement like follows ```#define GET_ELEMENTS(x) sizeof(x)>sizeof(uint8_t)?ARRAY_SIZE(x):sizeof(x)``` but it cannot be compiled even because macros are evaluated at compile time. Thank you for your time.