# How to check if a struct member exists in C?

Tags: c, struct, c99

How do I check if my structure has a member `something` in C99?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct some {
  char title[50];
  char name[50];
};

int main() {
  struct some s;

  if (*s.something) { // Error: no member named 'something' in 'struct.some'
    strcpy(s.something, "Hello");
  }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

I don't need to know if it exists at compile time, but in a built program. The members and their values will be parsed from a file and then consumed to the struct in a loop but I need to be sure that it will skip all non-existing members.

Comment: This would not compile, so this is how you would know. If you wanted to implement structures which can have members added or removed at runtime, it's a much more complex topic.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar No, I don't need a struct that can have members added or removed. I just need to check if a member exists, and give it a value if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read the file in question, you should know what each field is.  Since you know *at compile time* which ones you're interested, the code will only look for those fields.

Taking your sample `struct` containing a name and a title, suppose you have a file like this:

```
name:myname1,title:mytitle1,year:2016
name:myname2,title:mytitle2,year:2017
```

When you read each row, you'll find that each row contains fields named `name`, `title`, and `year`.  Since the struct in your code only knows about `name` and `title`, it would populate just those fields and should ignore the rest.

Here's some pseudo-code to illustrate:

```
void processline(char *line, struct some *data) {
    char key[50];
    char value[50];
    while (getnextpair(line,key,value)) {
        if (!strcmp(key, "name") {
            strcpy(data->name, value);
        } else if (!strcmp(key, "title") {
            strcpy(data->title, value);
        } else {
            printf("unknown field %s\n", key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your response. Perhaps this is the only way to go for C. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

C99 (or even C++) does not support reflection. So there is no way of checking if a struct contains a member with a particular name at runtime; the compiler will tell you at compile time instead.

This is different from other languages, like, for example, java, which support reflection.

Comment: C supports [generic selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28897994/975097), so it is possible to check the type of a struct at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a type field to all structs that might be checked. Add an enumeration to represent the types and use a method that takes a struct pointer, a type from the enumeration, and a method that returns a bool.
Then you could make something that's functionally equivalent and very close to what you tried to code.