# Passing variable number of arguments of different types in c

Tags: c

I want to make an function which will take variable number of arguments of different types. My problem is how can i parse the argument types. Like caller can pass arguments of any type in any order (without specifying format specifier). So at the calling function how can i differentiate between types.

How to print all values passed by the caller in the function var_argument ?

Let say I want to do sprintf inside var_argument function of the parameters passed by the caller

Here is my C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void var_argument(int num,...);

int main()
{
 var_argument(3,"Hello",7.87f,6);
 var_argument(3,7.87f,"Hello",6);
 return 0;
}

void var_argument(int num,...)
{
 char str[80];
/* What code should I write to differentiate between types and to print all the values passed by the caller */     

 va_list list;
 va_start(list,num);

 /* How to do sprintf of the parameter passed to this function and store 
 the formatted output in the array str  */
}
```

Comment: Do you know about `printf()`?

Comment: You need another parameter to give you the types of the arguments, that's the only (portable) way, e.g. like `printf` which deduces the type from the format specific (`%d`, `%f`, ...).

Comment: the argument before the `...` is traditionally meant to be something that indicates the types and the size is inferred from that

Comment: "I want to make an function which will take variable number of arguments of different types" Why? The need for a variadic function is almost always caused by muddy design - this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Lundin I would say, "*often*" instead of "*almost always*", because there are cases where it's actually a very elegant solution. For example, executing SQL prepared statements for *mysql*'s c library is a pain in the a**, but using a variadic function it can become a very simple thing to do.

Answer (score 7):

This is somehow already done, for example `printf()` has such mechanism. For variable arguments functions, you need a first parameter that is not part of the variable parameters, use it as a format string to determine the type of parameter *x* at position *n*.

Because the first parameter is mandatory, so you MUST have such a parameter and it seems natural to use it as an indicator of what to expect in the variable arguments.

Take this as an example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int
variable(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int count;

    va_start(args, format);

    count = 0;
    while (*format != '\0') {
        switch (*format++) {
            case 's':
                fprintf(stdout, "arg[%d]: %s\n", count, va_arg(args, const char *));
                break;
            case 'd':
                fprintf(stdout, "arg[%d]: %d\n", count, va_arg(args, int));
                break;
            case 'f':
                fprintf(stdout, "arg[%d]: %f\n", count, va_arg(args, double));
                break;
        }
        count += 1;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    variable("sdf", "Example", 3, 3.1416);
}
```

Of course, any mismatch between the specifiers and the actual types of the arguments will lead to undefined behavior and as a logical consequence to undesired behavior. So you must be very careful or, use `printf()` style specifiers and tell the compiler to warn if such mismatch occurs.

Another solution, is to do it like some of *glib*'s functions, pass a type specifier and immediately after the parameter, with a last value that would indicate the end of the parameters. Parameter "*specifiers*" could be an `enum` enumerating all supported types, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

enum types {
    String, Integer, Double, Float = Double, /* unless you want to store the value in a poitner
                                              * there is normally no difference between these
                                              */
    End
};

int
variable(enum types type, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int count;

    va_start(args, type);

    count = 0;
    while (type != End) {
        switch (type) {
            case String:
                fprintf(stdout, "arg[%d]: %s\n", count, va_arg(args, const char *));
                break;
            case Integer:
                fprintf(stdout, "arg[%d]: %d\n", count, va_arg(args, int));
                break;
            case Double:
                fprintf(stdout, "arg[%d]: %f\n", count, va_arg(args, double));
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "unknown type specifier\n");
                break;
        }
        type = va_arg(args, enum types);
        count += 1;
    }

    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    variable(String, "Example", Integer, 3, Double, 3.1416, End);
}
```

Comment: You can also use [_Generic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28897994/975097) to get the variable's type, instead of passing the type as a parameter.