# C equivalent for nested lists (Python)

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, nested

I am new to C and trying to learn by comparison with Python.

My question is trivial, but I still need some explanations from experts. Here is a Python nested list structure:

```
L = [1, [2, [3, 4], 5], 6, [7, 8]]
```

And here is an interesting piece of code (taken from 'Learning Python' by Lutz) to handle nested structures (sum elements):

```
def sumtree(L):
    tot = 0
    for x in L:
        if not isinstance(x, list):
            tot += x
        else:
            tot += sumtree(x)
    return tot
```

If I pass L into this function I will get 36, which is a sum of elements in L.
How exactly can nested lists and this particular function be translated into C?

Comment: Arrays in C are fixed length. If you want variable length, you will need a structure, involving pointers. Try reading up on structures and linked lists.

Comment: Your question is perfectly legitimate.  The answer, however, is that C doesn't support "list" as as a built-in construct.  You have to invent a "list" yourself, with constructs like "struct" or "array".

Comment: Python is a dynamic type language, with a lot of difference with C. You can't expect code in C like in python.

Comment: I don't expect the same code, I want the same result first of all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type is every element of `L`? It can be a number (an `int` for example in C), or even a list (it's typical for a list to be implemented with `struct`s in C).

In order to achieve that, you would need a generic list (i.e. that the data of every node is of type `void*`). Notice that C doesn't provide a list from the standard library, you have to write one (here is an [example](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/list-c/)).

Then, in order to get the sum, you would do something like that:

```
int sumtree(struct listnode * L) {
    int tot = 0;
    while (L != NULL) {
        if(L.data /* TODO: check if it is a number*/)
            tot += L.data;
        else /* L.data is a sublist */
            tot = sumtree(L.data);
        list = list->next;
    }
    return tot;
}
```

In order to get the type, you need to follow this answer: [How do I check if a variable is of a certain type (compare two types) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280055/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-of-a-certain-type-compare-two-types-in-c)

However, such nested lists in C are not common, and I would advise you to re-approach the issue.