# How to know if a variable is a function pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, typeof

I have a function of type `void(*func)(int)` and I get a pointer to this function, how can I know for sure that a pointer is really of this type?

```
if (typeof(pointer) == void(*func)(int)) {
    //do something     
}
```

Is that correct?

edit -
I get the pointer from a function as an argument and I want to check the type of the pointer inside this function.

Comment: If you have a `void (*pointer)(int)`, then its type *is* `void (*)(int)`. There's nothing to check. Why do you think it would be any different?

Comment: C is a statically typed language. By the time it gets into the variable it is a pointer of the specified type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a variable is of a certain type (compare two types) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280055/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-of-a-certain-type-compare-two-types-in-c)

Comment: @DeanTaler:  you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 4):

if you are getting your function pointer dynamically , so try to use union  to and a flag variable to get it's type without checking something complex

```
#define type1 1
#define type2 2
union FN
{
void ....
int ....
....
}

typedef struct{
int type;

union FN fn;
} Function;
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you add some sample code to your answer to make it more complete and not just a single sentence answer?

Comment: I´m not quite sure what you mean but note that the OP wants to have the check at runtime, not compile-time.

Comment: check it after editing ,it's useful for more dynamically ,but to be honest i don't know where he wants to get the pointer function from

Comment: but I want to chek the pointer inside a fucntion that gets the pointer, so it looks more complicate to do it in this way,  is there no easier option?

Comment: `void(*func)(int)` is like checking if `type==TYPE1`

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` not a part of the C standard.  It is a GNU extension.

If you want to be sure that something is of a particular type, you can handle it at compile-time with `_Generic` introduced in C11:

```
_Generic((pointer), 
    void(*)(int): /* insert your code here */,
)
```

If said pointer is not of type `void(*)(int)`, then it will fail to compile.

Answer (score 3):

If your function gets the *pointer* as an argument and has this prototype:

```c
void my_function(void (*func)(int)) {
    // How can I test if `func` really points to a function taking an `int`?
}
```

Then there is not much you can do inside the body of `my_function` to verify what `func` really points to.

- you can test if it is a null pointer:

  ```
  if (!func) { /* NULL was passed */ }
  ```
- you can test if it points to a known function:

  ```
  if (func == exit) { /* haha! (*func)(1) will abort */ }
  ```
- beyond the above, it is impossible to tell what was actually passed to `my_function`: it could be an actual function with the correct prototype, or another function implicitly or explicitly cast to the expected type or even some other scalar object with a cast.

If you want to write a macro whose expansion depends on the type of an expression, you can use the new C11 `_Generic` construction:

```c
#define IS_VOID_FUNC_OF_INT(func)  _Generic(func, void(*)(int): 1, default: 0)
```

But using this inside the body of function `my_function` above will always evaluate to `1`: only the defined type of `func` is tested by `_Generic`, not that of the original expression used as an argument to the function.