# Is C capable of printing variable type used in simple code and the occupied bytes in memories and the largest value it can hold?

Tags: c

simple code as:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 printf("%s", "Hello World\n");
 return 0;
}
```

is it possible to change output to display the variable type and the occupied X bytes in memory and the largest value it can hold?

thx in advance

Comment: What variable? There are no variables in your code. Please clarify your example and how it relates to your question.

Comment: C does not provide introspection, but you can certainly do things like `printf("x is an unsigned int with size %zd\n", sizeof x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not have any kind of reflection [before C11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28897994/5476674). To print the type of a variable, you can either hardcode it into the format string:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 0;
    printf("x is an int with a value of %d\n", x);
}

// prints "x is an int with a value of 0"
```

or you can use the macros in the linked answer.

To get the amount of memory a given variable occupies, you can use `sizeof`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 0;
    printf("x occupies %zu bytes in memory\n", sizeof(x));
}

// usually prints "x occupies 4 bytes in memory"
// (int's size is determined by the compiler)
```

There exists a [`limits.h`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) header that defines several macros for the maximum and minimum values of all built-in types. However, there is no way to dynamically get the maximum value of a given type aside from incrementing a variable until it overflows.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("int has a maximum value of %d\n", INT_MAX);
}

// usually prints "int has a maximum value of 2147483647"
// (int's maximum and minimum values are determined by the compiler)
```

Comment: @LookinForAnswers If this answered your question, you can click the checkmark underneath the vote buttons to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just clicked it