# How can I determine a variable type in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, variables, generics

For Example. I have this function -> `Sort(void * param)`  in which there is a generic parameter. I need to understand what is the type of the parameter passed cause the sorting of an Int is different from a char. So I need a similar situation :

```
Sort(void *param){
     if(param is int)
        //some code
     else if(param is char)
        //some code
     else if //ecc
}
```

I don't know how to write the code inside if statements.

Comment: I suggest you look at how the library function `qsort()` manages without knowing the type. Apart from being given the element size, it also needs a use-case `compare()` function (which also uses `void*`).

Comment: May be this link helps you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280055/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-of-a-certain-type-compare-two-types-in-c